# Mysql insert ignore, row_count()

Tags: mysql

how can I get the numbers of inserted rows, and duplicates, after an "INSERT IGNORE ... FROM".

when I execute the query I can see that on the output:

```
0 row(s) affected Records: 1530  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I can get affected rows with ROW_COUNT(), How can I get the duplicates field ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)?

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dublicate_flag = 1;
```

And after it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE dublicate_flag = 1;
```

Comment: Good though that would not cope with multiple duplicates I believe. (As in multiple for one record, maybe an increment, and a `SUM`.)

Comment: Yes, it can be expensive query.

Comment: Could be `duplicate_flag=duplicate_flag+1` to see how many duplicates you have, then `SUM(duplicate_flag)` to get a tally. You'd have to zero them out each time.